# Run Android lint on a single folder / package / custom scope

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

Is there a way to run a lint check on a single folder / package / custom scope through either Android Studio or from the command line.

I know how to target a module, uncommitted files, selected files. My workflow is usually to work in a branch and run lint checks / refactor before merging back to master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own answer rather by accident right after posting the question.

The `Analyze > Inspect` code dialog will change if you close all the code windows and select a folder / package in the solution window

[image]